# link not working above Jquery SVG Map

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, svg

I have a normal a tag link in a paragraph just above a Jquery SVG Map ( http://mapsvg.com/ ).

The link to "view a text version of food security networks". is visibly a link, but not clickable.

This is a wordpress site, and the link is added using advanced custom fields plugin, but I've tested that and I don't think it's the problem.

Can someone help me figure out what's broken?  I tried putting the link in the paragraph above but the client wants it just above the map.

It is also using bootstrap's tabbed panels.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've attached this function (from mapsvg-custom.js) to the link

```
$('#networks a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
})
```

The preventDefault prevents the link from working. Probably best not to attach this function in the first place i.e. fix the CSS not to match it.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the console, you get an error like this `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: http://gateway2.yourdevsite.pw/food-security-networks-list/`. Most likely, all links are being handled by a JS script somewhere and it is failing somehow.